# Web Map API needed for displaying multiple locations to user

Tags: dictionary, geolocation

What is a good map API that can display not just a static image, but the ability for the user to interact, zoom in and out. Additionally, what is a map API that can accept a street address and not a geo code?

update: Is it possible to get driving directions from an embedded map API? Such that the user can click onto a node and bring up a "where are you driving from?" prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [google maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/) would work well and you might also want to look into [ESRI's web mappings APIs](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisonline/web-mapping-apis.html) ([JavaScript](http://resources.esri.com/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/arcgis/index.cfm?fa=home), [Silverlight](http://resources.esri.com/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/arcgis/index.cfm?fa=home) and [Flex](http://resources.esri.com/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/arcgis/index.cfm?fa=home) versions available).

Regarding the address, all web mapping APIs are going to make you geocode an address to get a point on the map. This is trivial to do. All of the APIs I've mentioned provide a function to do this and you just have to handle a result.

Comment: So it appears we can transcode all of our basic mail addresses to geo codes from the API?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You'll be able to use functions in the API to translate (AKA geocode) your addresses to x,y coordinates you can plot on the map.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm a big fan of Google Maps, to be different, I'll suggest [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/). I haven't used it in any projects, but it looks quite promising.

OpenStreetMap also has a [geocoding function](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim), similar to Google Maps.